# How to create objects of protocol such that i can call the methods of it in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I have a protocol say

```
@protocol MyProtocol
-(void)mload 
@end
```

with a method `mload`, I also have ClassA which has implemented that protocol method ie mload.

```
@implementation ClassA
-(void)mload {
    NSLog(@"ClassA-mload");
}
@end
```

Now I need to call that method in another class say ClassB using an instance of ClassA. How to do that?

Comment: What, exactly, is `obj`? An instance of `ClassA`? A protocol object (`@protocol(MyProtocol)`)? If the latter, how do you decide which method to invoke, given that a protocol can declare more than one method?

Comment: obj is a protocol object
id<MyProtocol>obj;
Now i have to call the mload method in ClassB..

Comment: A "protocol object" is an instance of class Protocol; it's not the same as instance of a class that implements a protocol. `id<MyProtocol> obj` is much clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `ClassB` something like this, not sure how you're getting reference to `ClassA` obj but:

```
// obj is of type that implements protocol
id<MyProtocol> obj = [[ClassA alloc] init];
[obj load];


// should work as well because objective-c is dynamically typed so you can call
// any method on an object
id obj = [[ClassA alloc] init];
[obj load];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply i now tried it, this gives me a exception as NSInvalidArgumentException and [ClassB mload]:unrecognized selector sent to instance. How to solve the problem?

Comment: Did you implement `mload` in `ClassB`?